# Inserting page breaks in HTML email

Tags: html-email, page-break

I'm trying to place a page break into an HTML email using the following code but this does two things when I view the email in Outlook.

It ignores the line breaks in the 2nd table (only a problem with Outlook) and it does not page break (a problem in all non-web based email clients)!

Does anyone know how I can code this?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>test<br>test<br>test</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table style="page-break-before:always;">
    <tr>
        <td>me<br>me<br>me</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

send them a document instead of HTML, or link them to a page that contains your email HTML

I think you'll end up pulling out too much hair trying to get what you're doing to work correctly, especially as newer versions of email clients come out.